# What's the "where you're logged in" list all about and does it show incorrect information?

Tags: facebook

I have logged into my account via messenger on another device yesterday but later switched to another account. Then I went through Facebook's "Where you're logged in" list and it showed the name of the device with the accurate time. This morning, while again going through the "Where you're logged in" it showed the same device has logged into my account few seconds ago. When I checked for it on that device, it showed my account was last logged in 18 hours ago which was yesterday when I logged in. So what's the "where you're logged in" list all about and does it show incorrect information?

Answer (score -1):

Facebook is cheesy at best , think about how many people have it downloaded around the world, think about all the cons and ads trying to drain debits, then Facebook always asks you to make a new account.
I've got three or four gmail's tied into one account and the primary gmail is disabled because I went to prison for 2 years got out and gmail had closed my account and wouldn't open it back because I didn't have my old device and did not give me the security question option. Even though the information is the same.